# Is there any way to scrape a WordPress blog without being an owner of it?

Tags: wordpress, python-3.x, scrape, wordpress-rest-api

This may sound vaguely unethical, but it isn't so - I've been asked to make an app using data from a WordPress blog but I can't discuss adding a JSON API plugin through the admin panel right now. So I was wondering if there's a simple way to get all the posts from a blog with just their title, tags, and content.

Comment: "but I can't discuss adding a JSON API plugin through the admin panel right now." - can you elaborate this line please? It seems that you need a scrapper utility. Python has a powerful library for that but I think you're better off using BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @AlvinReyes As far as I can see from my research, there isn't any way to get post data from a blog, unless you add some plugin to it that adds JSON API capabilities. So I was wondering if I could scrape it manually or if there's any other API that I could use.

Comment: That's what I suggested. You can do this by scraping the content off using BeautifulSoup (if you're using Python) or JSoup (if you're using Java). Both are extremely useful HTML parsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, there's an extremely simple way. As far as I can tell, however, this will only work for blogs hosted on `wordpress.com` itself. This doesn't require any authentication, but you'll only get public posts.

```
https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/$sitename.wordpress.com/posts/
```

With `$sitename` being the site ID. This will elicit a fairly comprehensive JSON response that'll give you the title, content, tags, etc of all the public posts on the blog. Pretty cool, but very hard to find.